# Converting from pointer to c-array reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, reinterpret-cast

Is it possible to convert allocated memory into a reference to c-array without invoking undefined behavior?

I have 4 elements in the heap and want to see it as a 2x2 c-array (to pass to a function for example).
I use `reinterpret_cast` here. Is there something else, less drastic than `reinterpret_cast` that I can do?

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
double f(double(&ref)[2][2]) {
    return ref[0][0] + ref[1][1];
}


int main() {
    double* data = new double[4];
    data[0] = 1; data[1] = 1; data[2] = 1; data[3] = 1;

    auto& array = reinterpret_cast<double(&)[2][2]>(*data);
//  auto& array = *reinterpret_cast<double(*)[2][2]>(data);

    f(array);
    delete[] data;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/84Kxjoqjq

clang-tidy recommend plainly not using `reinterpret_cast`.

Sonar Lint says that this use of `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behavior.

`dereference of type 'double *[2][2]' that was reinterpret_cast from type 'double *' has undefined behavior`

Comment: Sure. Just serve up a reference to an object that implements an `operator[]` overload, that returns another object that also implements an `operator[]` overload, that resolves to the appropriate value. I would expect that modern compilers will optimize away all the temporaries to produce the expected code, no fuss, no mess.

Comment: C++23 [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) is for such tasks. Unfortunately, only [MSVC](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) supports it nowadays.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I cannot change the signature of `f` if that is what you mean.

Comment: And you "cannot change the signature of `f`" why, exactly? No, there is no way to do this cleanly in C++.

Comment: There is no way to get a pointer to an array from a pointer to its element without invoking UB. Separately from that, there is no way to view a 4-element array as a 2×2-element 2D array, or vice versa, without invoking UB. Perhaps you could allocate a struct with a 2×2 array as its only member.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's undefined behavior and strictly by the standard, there is no way to do what you want without UB.

You either have a `double[4]` or a `double[2][2]`. The memory can't hold both in their lifetime at the same time and treating it as if it does will cause undefined behavior.

There was some proposal to add certain aliasing permissions of this kind to the standard, at least when wrapping in a class type via explicit layout annotations. See [P1912](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/655). However that proposal doesn't seem to have seen any progress since 2020.

Of course, a `std::start_lifetime_as` (C++23) could be used to change the type of the object at the memory location that is in its lifetime from `double[4]` to `double[2][2]`. Then you are good to go, assuming you use the return value from `std::start_lifetime_as` (otherwise a `std::launder` is needed).

This would not generally work though if the `double[4]` array was a subobject of another object or if it was a `const` complete object with automatic/static/thread storage duration. The preconditions of `std::start_lifetime_as` must be satisfied. It is not possible to use it to avoid the `std::launder` reachability conditions which make it impossible to ever reach any memory other than that of the four `double` in the array from a pointer to one of its elements.

Also, `std::start_lifetime_as` replaces the object. The old object is not in its lifetime anymore afterwards. Therefore you can't use this if anyone relies on that still being the case. E.g. it isn't claer whether `delete[] data;` would be ok. The language in [expr.delete] doesn't seem very clear to me.

Comment: Can I at least get a `double[4]` from the `pointer`?

Comment: @alfC Yes, with `*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<double(*)[4]>(data))`. It is only valid though if this doesn't make any bytes outside the 4 doubles accessible, i.e. if the array is part of another array or a first member of a standard-layout class, then the `std::launder` call will be UB.

Comment: Like this `auto& array = *std::start_lifetime_as<double(*)[2][2]>(data);`? (not implemented yet in GCC it seems. https://godbolt.org/z/WMM3zje9K.

Comment: @alfC `*std::start_lifetime_as<double[2][2]>(data);` But yes, likely not implemented yet.

Comment: Nice C++! Introduced UB everywhere then started to fight against UB with `std::launder`, `std::start_lifetime_as`...

Comment: @273K `std::start_lifetime_as` is just a helper that has been missing since forever. `std::launder` and the rules around it were introduced for multiple reasons, one of which is to handle `const` object replacement in a reasonable manner. However, with the changes to the meaning of pointer values they also introduced conditions which allow a compiler to make more optimizations based on assumptions from object structure (e.g. you generally can't traverse memory to reach sibling objects). I don't know why this was introduced, I am not aware of any compiler making use of it.